# how to use ssscanf with matrix of strings in c

Tags: c, string, matrix, scanf

I want to save some strings in a matrix of string. The problem is that I get this error: *segmentation fault core dumped*. I researched on the internet but I haven't any example that showed how to use ssscanf with string matrix.

```
char * b[20][4];
sscanf("one two three","%s %s %s",b[0][0], b[0][1],b[0][2]);
printf("%s %s %s",b[0][0], b[0][1],b[0][2]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
char b[20][8]; // three has five characters, lose the * to allocate memory
sscanf("one two three","%s %s %s",b[0], b[1],b[2]);
printf("%s %s %s\n",b[0], b[1],b[2]);
```

Comment: yes, this works, but if I use char * b[20] why do i get segmentation core dumped

Comment: isn't char * b[20] a matrix of chars ?

Comment: No it is an array of pointers that do not reference any memory.

Comment: Really do consider reading this tutorial: http://pw1.netcom.com/~tjensen/ptr/pointers.htm